# Why does the mixed partial derivative of $ sin(x)+sin(y)=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I wonder why and how it works. Please show me the steps, thanks

Comment: Think about what happens when you take $\partial^2/(\partial x\partial y)$ of any function of the form $f(x) + g(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=\sin(x)+\sin(y)$. Then $f_x(x,y)=\cos(x)$, which is independent of $y$. Therefore:

$f_{yx}(x,y)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

When you differeniate wrt. $x$, you have $\cos x$, which is constant wrt. $y$.